# Jericho plain text how to separate text

Tags: java, html

I am trying to parse the plain text using Jericho with the following code:

```
    public static String getPlainText(String html) {
    Source htmlSource = new Source(html);
    Segment htmlSeg = new Segment(htmlSource, 0, html.length());
    Renderer htmlRend = new Renderer(htmlSeg);
   // System.out.println(htmlRend.toString());
    return htmlRend.toString();
}
```

However for the following html fragment:

```
    Phone (808) 845-0000<br />
    Fax (808) 842-3616
    <a href="mailto:helpdesk@progressive-hi.com">
    helpdesk@progressive-hi.com</a>
```

I am getting the output:

> Phone (808) 845-0000 Fax (808) 842-3616helpdesk@progressive-hi.com

Now all I wanted is all the texts within the tags should be separated from one another ie fax and email should be separated from each other. Is there any way to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.

```
Source source=new Source(new URL(sourceUrlString));
System.out.println(source.getTextExtractor().setIncludeAttributes(true).toString());
```

http://jericho.htmlparser.net/samples/console/src/ExtractText.java

Comment: Tell us how you solved it and mark you answer as the "correct answer".

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Instead, vote up the answers that you find helpful.